# condition is not working please guide me how to get proper data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_property` 
WHERE 
    `sublocality` LIKE '%dwarka%' OR 
    `sublocality` LIKE '%delhi%' OR 
    `property_type` LIKE '%1%' OR
    `property_type` LIKE '%2%' AND
    `status` = 1 AND 
    `property_category` = 1
```

this is my query but where condition is not working please guide me how to get proper data with this type of sql query

[image]

Comment: "not working" in what way? It's providing result, isn't it? Please explain why this result is not what you expect, and what result you do expect.

Comment: Don't trust the associativity of expressions in WHERE clauses and ON clauses (the associativity of AND and OR).  They don't work the way you think.

Comment: @rickdenhaan actually, and condition status =1 and property_category = 1 not working properly. Please check the query and result in the query I mention propert_category =1 but in the result section I got the  propert_category =2

Comment: @Ricky That behavior is indeed caused by the lack of parentheses, as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to add parentheses in your query to group OR/AND conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_property` 
WHERE 
(
    `sublocality` LIKE '%dwarka%' OR 
    `sublocality` LIKE '%delhi%' OR 
    `property_type` LIKE '%1%' OR
    `property_type` LIKE '%2%'
) AND
    `status` = 1 AND 
    `property_category` = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you should describe in your question what your desired result would look like and what you are trying to query, as it is not clear right now.

Second, you should not use `LIKE` for non-text searches, but use the equals operator `=`.

Third, you probably need braces `( and )` for grouping parts of your query, as you use OR and AND in one query, they will be mixed up.

So, I will try to give an example.. Let's say you want to find properties with `sublocality = 'delhi'` and property id `1`, you should write:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `tbl_property` WHERE `sublocality` LIKE 'delhi' AND `property_type` = 1;
```

Now, if you want to get property 1, in both delhi and dwarka sublocalities, you could write:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `tbl_property` WHERE (`sublocality` LIKE 'delhi' OR `sublocality` LIKE 'dwarka') AND `property_type` = 1;
```

This way, you make sure that `part1betweenbraces` AND `part2` are matched. If you don't add the braces, it will evaluate to:

```sql
WHERE `sublocality` LIKE 'delhi' OR (`sublocality` LIKE 'dwarka' AND `property_type` = 1);
```

So always make sure you add braces when mixing `OR`'s and `AND`'s in one query.